# How to hide admin menu in admin panel

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I used Drupal 6 and admin menu module. Im need hide admin menu in admin panel. I write module, but it doesn't work. Help me please

Module code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function YOURMODULE_init() {
  global $theme_key;
  if ($theme_key == 'rootcandy') {
    module_invoke('admin_menu', 'suppress');
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Check the configuration of admin menu module

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the theme globals aren't set by the time you're referring to them in `hook_init()`. You could call `theme_init()` before you check for the `$theme_key` value, but I'm not sure if this has unintended side-effects.